# How is Friendly URL or pretty URL is actually implemented?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I see many sites where they use something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/someinfo/somenumber
```

and then they use the 'somenumber' at the end to display content.
I dont think they make a page for every number (since there are more than 1000 numbers, How do they do this?

Edit: They even do it on this site: if you look at the url the last bit (using-url-directories-in-php).

Comment: Study about htaccess

Comment: I didn't know what seo friendly questions where, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file in your website's `dir` and paste the following code in it:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

There are many more things that `htaccess` could do for you, like blocking bad bots, ip block users (Not recommended on `localhost` server. You could try if you want.), redirect to a website, etc...

Comment: Guess that would do, it work on my.

Comment: What do the last three lines of this code do?

Comment: The last 3 line of code is to hide the extension of the file. I set it to hide `php` and `html`.

Comment: Also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then proceed to the rewrite rule below.